# How to unittest that a django model method called with unittest.mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use `unittest.mock` library.
I have this model:

```
from django.db import models

class Data(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    // ... more fields

    _PASSWORD_KEY = 'some_random_password_key'
    _password = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='password')

    def _set_password(self, raw_password):
        """
        Encode raw_password and save as self._password
        """
        // do some Vigenère magic

    def _get_password(self):
        """
        Decode encrypted password with _PASSWORD_KEY and return the original.
        """
        return raw_password

    password = property(_get_password, _set_password)
```

I want to test that `_set_password` is called when I do `data = Data(password='password')`.
I manually confirmed it is called, but this unit test fails (which I brought from the examples of unittest.mock documentation):

```
from mock import patch
from someapp.models import Data

def test_set_password_is_called(self):
    with patch.object(Data, '_set_password') as password_method:
        data = Data(password='password123')

    password_method.assert_called_once_with('password123')
```

With this message:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/walkman/project/someapp/tests.py", line 75, in test_set_password_is_called
    password_method.assert_called_once_with('password123')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 845, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: mock documentation has an [example for mocking properties](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock) using `PropertyMock`. Maybe that would help?

Comment: `with patch('tracker.models.PlayingHistoryAudit._set_password', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_password:` doesn't do the trick either :(

Comment: Note the example doesn't mock the setter but the property itself, i.e. `patch('tracker.models.PlayingHistoryAudit.password', ..)` ... hmm, but just realized that might not be suitable for checking the setter gets called.

Comment: Exactly! I want to check that the setter do it's job correctly. Maybe the way to check it is by looking up the _password property after the assignment.

Comment: It might be easiest for you to change your test and determine that the setter (i.e. _set_password) does what you expect by testing value is what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because password is a property and attributes on the property class getter and setter are used in the calling stack you don't end up calling the patched attribute on the class. You can change the test, akin to described here

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2011_06_04.shtml

Notice this works

```
class Test(object):

def test(self):
    return self.test2()


def test2(self):
    print("This was Called")
```

and the test

```
with patch.object(Test, 'test2') as mock_method:
    d = Test()
    d.test()

mock_method.assert_called()
```

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you are talking about. What does mean "attributes on the property class getter and setter are used in the calling stack you don't end up calling the patched attribute on the class" ? If you set property a value, the setter method will be called in this case `_set_password`. My problem is, that my test is wrong and doesn't detect this.

Comment: Since you defined password as a property, your class calls methods as defined when setting and getting the value. Except the call isn't as you expect and instead uses predefined methods in the property class. You can change your test, to call your method directly. Since unittest.patch is expecting a call directly on the method.

Comment: So when setting the password property, that is not working the way I think it work ?

Comment: NO, it works in exactly the why you think (more or less). The problem is that it does not work behind the scene the way you think it should work with patch to be able to test the way you would like.